# Injecting a keypress into a tool started by a bash script

Tags: bash, aix

I'm writing a bash script to gather some informations about disks and then start the 'nmon' tool to monitor only those specific disks.

I start the nmon tool out of the bash script (with `-g`). To get the correct view within the tool one need to press the <kbd>g</kbd> key on the keyboard.

Is there any way to get that keypress automatically triggered out of the bash script?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo -n "g" | nmon
```

For more infomation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264596/simulating-enter-keypress-in-bash-script

Or use [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) (`man expect` comes with examples).

Answer (score 0):

[nmon](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_72/n_commands/nmon.html) supports an `NMON` shell variable where you can preemptively place those keystrokes; I typically use `export NMON=cmt` in my shell profile, but you could use:

```
NMON=g nmon -g /path/to/diskgroup/file
```

or

```
export NMON=g
nmon -g /path/to/diskgroup/file
```

.. in your bash script that invokes `nmon`.